# Why a 3rd column family when creating a custom index on Cassandra?

Tags: indexing, cassandra

As I always say, sorry for my English. I'm working on creating some manual indexes for some column families in Cassandra. I have read everything I could about this but I have found something I'm not able to understand properly.

In this presentation [Indexing in Cassandra, pages 36 to 45](http://www.slideshare.net/edanuff/indexing-in-cassandra), done by Ed Anuff, I have seen his simple example for creating an index for a Users column family. He uses the 2 obvious CFs and another one to deal with concurrency. This third CF is "my problem". If I'm not wrong, Cassandra will always store the most recent value for each column. If this value is indexed, I have to update it in the Index CF (delete old index and create the new one), but why it is necessary the third CF? When I think about that and the concurrency, what my understanding says is: ok, many people updating a value which is indexed. It will mean a lot of work updating the index, but finally the last value will be in the Users CF and also in the Index CF, that's why there is a timestamp per column, so what's the matter with the concurrency? Even more, if the value can be updated only by one user (the owner of the data), there will be no concurrency...

I know I am a big ignorant in Cassandra affairs, but I don't see the reason behind the third CF. Ed Anuff explains that using this third column family you can restore the indexes to a consistent status [here](http://www.anuff.com/2010/07/secondary-indexes-in-cassandra.html), but, why are them going to fall into an inconsistent status? And, if this happens, the Users CF could be enough to restore the index, or am I wrong?

Please, could someone explain me this? What is/are my error/s?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I think someone else could have the same doubt than me, I'm going to answer my own question with the things I have found:

As I supposed the main problem is the concurrency. If we assume that many users at the same time can be changing the same indexed value, as you have to read the index before updating, between the time you read a value and the time you update a value in the index another user could have changed again that value. As well as, from the moment the value is updated until you update the index the system could crash. Then, after a few concurrent changes the index could have old values that point to rows that have not that value.

By adding the third column family this process is safer but NOT 100% SAFE.

And a last thing: from my understanding, if there is no concurrency when updating the values, then there must be no problem. Let's supose you are indexing some user data. If  only the owner of the data is allowed to modify the data, there is no concurrency at all. The unique risk is the system crashes before you finish the process to align the index with the value, but this operation is idempotent, so you can repeat it until success.

Hope this explain what I have understood and help others.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it's more about idempotency rather than concurrency. 
If you have two column families or three, concurrent users may produce false positive results, i.e. keys in the index column family that point to the rows which don't have that value anymore... but with two column family design if you repeat any part of updating process you may end up losing the key of a row in the correct row of index column family... however with three column family design you are sure that you **have** the key of each row in the correct place in index column family... 
filtering the results will solve the false positive problem but if you don't have the key in the correct place, you can't obtain the row simply and whole indexing mechanism will be in vain...

consider this example on  a two column family design:
user 1 updates the location, Cassandra returns error but write was successful.
user 2 updates the location, reads result of user 1 write and writes his location in column family
user 1 re-tries and writes his location in the column family and updates index column family
user 2 updates index column family and deletes user 1 location and inserts his own

at last user has the location of user 1 but row key only exists in the user 2 input index row

I make the example right now and it may have some problem in it or you may solve the problem of losing the key in the right place by changing the update process, but you should understand the concept behind. you can think of a better example.

however I'm not sure about this, but this explanation makes sense to me and hopefully I could explain it to you...